# How to disable a component based on viewModel store returnrd data extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, viewmodel, extjs5, sencha-architect

I have two comboboxes and I want the combox(b) to be disabled based on the selected value from combobox A(I should look at its store data find the records and if the records parameter(arsubOpen) consists a value 1 then only I should enable the combobox B ). For this I have added a similar store like A and added a filter to filter the records which contain only arsubOpen 1. Now how do I make them enable them based on those store records.

[Test fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25sr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to `change` event and compare the new value with any value you want to enable the second combobox:

```
 {
    xtype: 'combobox',
    anchor: '100%',
    displayField: 'description',
    valueField: 'adjustmentTypeId',
    fieldLabel: 'A',
    // lastQuery: '' to disable store loading a second time on trigger click
    lastQuery: '',
    bind: {
        store: '{a}'
    },
    listeners: {
        change: function( combo, value ) {
            // Logging a value to console - remove this code
            console.log( value );

            var store = combo.getStore();
            var record = store.findRecord(combo.valueField, value)
            var arsubOpen = record.get('arsubOpen');
            // Condition for enabling here
            var shouldEnable = arsubOpen === 1;

            var form = combo.up( 'form' );
            var basicForm = form.getForm();
            // 'bField' si the name of the B combobox field
            var bCombo = basicForm.findField( 'bField' );
            bCombo.setDisabled( !shouldEnable );
        }
    }
},
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    anchor: '100%',
    // Field name to use for form submitting and finding the field
    name: 'bField',
    displayField: 'description',
    valueField: 'arOnlySubCategoryId',
    fieldLabel: 'B',
    // lastQuery: '' to disable store loading a second time on trigger click
    lastQuery: '',
    bind: {
        disabled: 'disableB',
        store: '{B}'
    }
}
```

A [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25t6) based on your own.

I threw in `lastQuery: ''` configuration to disable the store loading a second time on the trigger click, which can be really annoying and took me a lot of hours to figure out a solution.

Comment: Thanks marathy but the key here is to enable and disable based on the other parameter in the same record. Ex:  "arsubOpen": "0" {"adjustmentTypeId": 7,"type": "M","invoiceType": "M","description": "Miscellaneous","createUserId": "9","createDateTime": 1412711611023,"updateUserId": "21","updateDateTime": 1475603316810,"invoiceCode": "MS","categoryCode": "MS","active": true,"arsubOpen": "0"} this is the record for Miscellaneous. So I need to check this record and see if "arsubOpen" is 0 or 1 if it is 1 i need to enable B

Comment: Do you use the combobox for anything else? If not, you can just define its `valueField` as `'arsubOpen'`. If yes, you can use `var record = combo.getStore().findRecord(combo.valueField, value)`.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay thanks Marthy I have one more question  when the B combobox is enabled I want to show the dropdown values only if the adjustmentTypeId matches with the adjustmentTypeId from the selected value in A. Ex: A/R and Quantity have arSubOpen as 1. so we are enabling them based on that check, next I need to check from the B store json parameters if the adjustmentTypeId is matched with the selected A value(adjustmentTypeId) and then only show the drop down values. Updated json chage for the B store https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2609

Comment: I mean to say to display only those records/values only if the adjustmentType Id matches

Comment: You can use B store filter for that, and after check if the store contains any filtered records by using [`store.count()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-count), it counts filtered records.